# form CSS for input fields

Tags: html, css

I have a form like

```
<form class="mystyle" ...>
<input name="test1" type="text">
<input name="test2" type="text">
...
</form>
```

Now I would like to style all the inputs with CSS:

```
.mystyle input[type="text"] {
   width: 200px;
 }
```

I know it would work to give the inputs a class. But if you have a large number of inputs this is not an optimal solution...

How do I make the inputs to inherit the class of the form?

Comment: this also work `input[type="text"] {
   width: 200px;
 }` fine if you wana apply style to all inputs without class

Comment: Thanks Shehary. But now all the text inputs in the other forms (not having class "mystyle") also show this special style :-(

Comment: What's not working in your current approach? Looks fine to me.

Comment: What about `form.mystyle input {
  width : 200px;
 }`

Comment: You can't make it inherit the class. You can make it inherit properties though. Just apply the styles like you are doing it now. Whats wrong with that?

Comment: Robby: Firefox just ignores it... also Chromium.

Comment: @Peter i just checked the code in question in fiddle in both chrome and firefox, work like charm http://jsfiddle.net/fh65hshk/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nfxg3jy0/

Comment: I even checked in Chromium. Works without a problem.

Comment: OP can you make a Fiddle showing it doesn't work.

Comment: This is odd. It seems to work in a test page, but not on my Typo3 backend page. So I think there is a conflict with some strange CSS of the Typo3 backend. I will check that out and post the results of my investigation. Thanks to all meanwhile!

Comment: Check in your console, inspect the element and see where the styles for your `input` are (also) defined.

Comment: This question attracts way too many people that are desperate to get downvoted :) OP, consider deleting it and posting a new one when you have identified a real issue.

Comment: try to solve by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it again with **!important** and it worked. This seems to overrule some CSS from Typo3.

A good hint to all Typo3-Backend-Programmers: If some CSS does not work, try to fix it with !important first.

When there is time, I will investigate, what Typo3 does here to my CSS. Thanks to all the help!

Comment: If you make your selectors more specific that should override Typo3s CSS, unless they use `important` themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with jquery If you wanna :

```
<form class="mystyle" ...>
<input name="test1" type="text">
<input name="test2" type="text">
...
</form>
```

css

```
.mystyle input.text {
   width: 200px;
 }
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("form.mystyle input").addClass("text")})
```

Comment: Why? There is no need for JavaScript.

Comment: Good solution to what when there is no problem

Comment: This is not a solution. You shouldn't need JavaScript to solve a CSS problem. It's probably to do with not being specific enough. The styles might get overwritten by something else.

Comment: yes but these codes more useful

$(document).ready(function(){ $("form.mystyle input").style("width","200px")})

Comment: No, it's not more useful. It adds unnecessary bytes to your website AND it is not good for accessibility: e.g. when someone doesn't have JS turned on.

Comment: @budamivardi More useful how? More useful in the sense that you're required to load a 100K script file, and execute unnecessary code to fix a styling issue? I guess when you only have a hammer, everything starts looking like a nail.